# JafaFX-8: ComboBox - watch the old and new values on field blur

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx-8, scenebuilder

Is it possible to get the previous & current selected text values of a JavaFX ComboBox on field blur?

Sample: 
 
On combobox focus - value is 'Item A' 
 
On blur - new value is 'Item B'

I'm looking for something that will go on the 'missing logic' part below:

```
public void foo(){
    myComboBox.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldProp, newProp) -> doSomething(newProp, myTextField));
}

private void doSomething(boolean isFocused, TextField myTextField){
   if(isFocused){
   // Do something
   } else {
   // =====MISSING LOGIC=====
   // I need to check whether myComboBox value has changed during this
   // field blur before doing something with myTextField

     updateTextFieldValue();
   }
}
```

I do know that I can somehow use a valueProperty listener instead of focusedProperty to achieve what I want but I'm looking for a way that would fit the current code easier.

What I've tried so far: 
Have tried watching the combobox on debug and look for possible properties where I can get the previous and current value but am unable to.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `SelectionModel` to do that, the `focusedProperty()` is for the control itself not the items, and sorry if i can't use `Lambdas` :

```
cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

            if(oldValue != null){

                System.out.println("Old: " + oldValue);

            }else{

                System.out.println("no older value");

            }

            System.out.println("New: " + newValue);

        }
    });
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I was trying out valueProperty() and I also tried  selectionModel. Both are getting triggered every time cb.setValue(foo); is being called (which I think is kind of strange for selectionModel.selectedItemProperty()). Unfortunately I did not find a way to get the values on blur. I had refactor the code to have 2 listeners instead - one for focused prop and another for selectedItem. Anyway, thanks again!